my ip and my domain showing different result
Hello there I am trying access my website through domain I am using a VPS and A domain in different websites but when I try to access my domain it access successfully but some time it show nginx on the other side when I access my domain through ip it show ssl certificate I  tried to access website after deleting history through domain I worked in here not in my friend laptop and SSL was not working in his can anyone provide a solution to this.
site domain: master-schema.com 
site ip    : 38.242.154.32

please try to change http to https vice versa to check in your side
Edit


You must have some configuration to redirect http to https.  What is it?  It looks like it is redirecting the IP address to HTTPS which it sholudn't do.

Your SSL certificate doesn't cover the www. subdomain. It looks like a lets-encrypt cert.  How are you generating it?  Are you able to add an subject alternate name (SAN) for www?

@StephenOstermiller I kind don't know where this configuration is I am using aapanel and webmin and I am managing vps server the direction of domain is correct from domain provider but the ip address I am not sure where it is coming from. however, ngnix setup by aapanel is in path www/ngnix/server/html but site is in www/wwwroot something like that and he read both

@StephenOstermiller I kind don't know what SAN is and SSL certificate is assigned to domain name provider not host provider which is different

As @StephenOstermiller said, the problem is nothing to do with your domain or IP - it has to do with the configuration of your website in your control panel - and relatedly the SSL certificate you have generated does not include the "www.master-schema.com" (which is what is meant by SAN - Subject Alt Name - a field in the certificate).  You would change this in aapanel.  If https://azdigi.com/blog/en/webserver-panel-en/aapanel-en/how-to-add-a-website-to-aapanel/ is anything to go by - when you add a site, you need to add both master-schema.com and www.master-schema.com to the Domain field,

@davidgo I added the www  version of my website but still the issue is going can you please check

Thats working fine for me.
